# Simplifying an expression $(A \cap B) \cup \{[(A \cap B) \cap (C \cap D)] \cup (A \cap B)\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have this exercise

> $(A \cap B) \cup \{[(A \cap B) \cap (C \cap D)] \cup (A \cap B)\}$

and I need to simplify. The first thing I would do be join $(A \cup B)$ like this:
$$ (A \cap B) \cup [(A \cap B) \cap (C \cap D)]$$
Analogously
$$ (A \cap B) \cup [C \cap D].$$
Its correct my attemp? And what will be the next step? How can I wil reduce that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First simplify $\{...\}$. $$[(A \cap B) \cap (C \cap D)] \cup (A \cap B)=A\cap B$$ because $(A \cap B) \cap (C \cap D)$ is a subset of $A\cap B$. So what you have is just $$(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B)$$ which is $$A \cap B.$$

I have used the fact that $E\cup F=F$ if $E\subseteq F$.